# When applying CAGradientLayer to a cell, How can I bring one of the cells' views forward so it is not affected by the gradient?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cagradientlayer

I have a tableview cell that has a text label within it. I have applied a gradient to the cell using this code:

```
if(cell.layer.sublayers.count == 2){ 
            let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
            gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.clearColor().CGColor, UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor]
            gradientLayer.locations = [0.6, 1.0]
            gradientLayer.frame = cell.bounds
            cell.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, atIndex: UInt32(1))
        }
```

The cell consists of an image view and a label. I have considered adding the gradient to the imageView, but because I am using a parallax effect in the imageView it causes the gradient to move out of place when scrolling.

How can I bring the label in front of the gradient that is applied by CAGradientLayer? Or how can I  cause the label to not be affected by the gradient?

Comment: Are you applying the gradient to the cell from outside the cell's implementation?

Comment: This is within the tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath) function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a subclass for your cell and override `layerClass` method so that it returns `CAGradientLayer`.

Then instead of adding a sublayer, add the gradient directly to `self.layer`. You can do it in cell's `init` or `awakeFromNib` method.

```
override class func layerClass() -> AnyClass {
    return CAGradientLayer.self
}

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier!)

    let gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = self.layer as CAGradientLayer
    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.clearColor().CGColor, UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor]
    gradientLayer.locations = [0.6, 1.0]
```

}

Comment: I'm confused about the part where you say "add the gradient directly to `self.layer`".I have already created a subclass of UITableCell because I made a custom cell. Whenever I try to access the layers for the second argument of `insertSublayer` I get a runtime error. How can I insert the gradient to `self.layer` without using the `insertSublayer` method?

Comment: Just cast `self.layer` to `CAGradientLayer`. See my edited answer. If you use storyboards or .xib files, add gradient in `awakeFromNib:` instead.